# How to retrieve variables after include function in php

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

I have added a user restriction to a page using the include function, but this action empty my variables, so after login, results are not shown because of this, how can I keep the variables along the script? I thought session was the way, but it does not work.

```
<?php
$trim=$_POST['trim'];
$estu=$_POST['estu'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['trim'] = $trim;
$_SESSION['estu'] = $estu;

if($trim == "RJ") {
echo "<h2>Login required!</h2>";
include ("../admin/accesusers.php");
}

$trim = $_SESSION['trim'];
$estu = $_SESSION['estu'];
echo "Your choices are ".$trim." and ".$estu; 
?>
```

So last echo's output is... **Your choices are and** ...because the variables are not retrieved when `$trim == "RJ"` oterwise results are good, for instance  **Your choices are *T1* and *3323***

file accesusers.php:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','usr','pass','Dbase');
include_once("login.php");
$_auth = new auth($db); // Anything past here is logged in
$username = $_auth->getUsername();
?>
```

At the **login.php** file, the only variable mentioning **SESSION** is this one, could it be this one messing the things up?

```
define('LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED',-8);
....
LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED=>'<br /><h3>Your session is outdated!</h3>',
....
die($this->form(LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED,'signin'));
```

Comment: At first use `session_start()` once on top and never repeate this on same page After that make sure you have the data on $_POST['trim] and $_POST['estu']

Comment: I assume this code is not from the same script/file. Can you split them up please? And also please explain what that admin script does.

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Yes if  you echo `$trim=$_POST['trim'];` you can see the variable.

Comment: You're calling `session_start()` twice in one file? Don't do that.

Comment: @Jeto I added file accesusers.php

Comment: @GregSchmidt so how can it be done?

Comment: Just call it once at the top, and then the session is good for the remainder of that request.

Comment: @GregSchmidt it does not work

Comment: Are your `$_SESSION` values definitely set correctly before you include `accesusers.php`? Is `login.php` maybe calling `session_start` again? It must be called once per *request*, not once per *file*.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have added som more info regarding your question. And files accesusers.php and login.php are not opening `$_SESSION`

Comment: `login.php`, or your `auth` class, or something that they include, must be doing something with the session, is my only guess. The code you've shown looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally solved. I've realized that only when the `include()` is inside the `if` the variables get lost, and also that the `$_SESSION` has to get the value from `$_POST` and not from the variable (`$trim`) to spread this value; so I did a workaround this way:

**File 1.php**:

```
<?php
$trim = $_POST['trim'];
$estu = $_POST['estu'];
if($trim == 'RJ') {
        header( 'Location: 2.php' ) ;
        session_start();
$_SESSION['estu'] = $_POST['estu'];
$_SESSION['trim'] = $_POST['trim'];
} else {
echo "<p>Your choices are ".$trim." and ".$estu."</p>";
}
?>
```

**File 2.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
$estu = $_SESSION['estu'];
$trim = $_SESSION['trim'];
echo "<h2>Login required!</h2>";
include ("../admin/accesusers.php");
echo "<p>Your choices are ".$trim." and ".$estu."</p>";
?>
```

So now the output is "*Your choices are **RJ** and **3323***"